# How can I use 'in-page link' by # when using Kaminari?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I have this in my view

```
 <%= paginate @comments, :window => 4, :outer_window => 2 %>
```

This automatically creates pagination links. If I click one of them, it takes me to
http://example.com/shop/walmart?page=2

How can I add in-page link, which takes me to this url?
http://example.com/shop/walmart?page=2#abc

Supposing #abc is the destination here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= paginate @comments, :window => 4, :outer_window => 2 , :params => {:anchor => "abc"} %>
```